# Why do I get class, enum, interface expected?

Tags: java, parsing, interface, hashmap, delimiter

```
/**
 * @(#)b.java
 *
 *
 * @author
 * @version 1.00 2012/5/4
 */
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.*;



public class b {

static void lireBddParcs(String nomFichier) throws IOException
{
    LinkedHashMap parcMap = new LinkedHashMap<Parc,Collection<Manege>> ();


    boolean existeFichier = true;

    FileReader fr = null;

    try
    {
        fr = new FileReader (nomFichier);
    }

    catch(java.io.FileNotFoundException erreur)
    {
        System.out.println("Probleme rencontree a l'ouverture du fichier" + nomFichier);
        existeFichier = false;
    }

    if (existeFichier)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(nomFichier));

                   while (scan.hasNextLine())
                   {

                       String[] line = scan.nextLine().split("\t");
                       Parc p = new Parc(line[0], line[1], line[2]);
                       parcMap.put(p, null);

                   }

              }
                  scan.close();
    }

}

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException
    {
      lireBddParcs("parcs.txt");


    }
}
```

parc.txt contains:

```
Great America   Chicago Illinois
Magic mountain  Los Ageles  Californie
Six Flags over Georgia  Atlanta Georgie
Darien Lake Buffalo New York
La Ronde    Montreal    Quebec
The Great Escape    Lake Georges    New York
Six Flags New Orleans   New Orleans Louisiane
Elitch Gardens  Denver  Colorado
Six Flags over Texas    Arlington   Texas
Six Flags New England   Springfield Massachusetts
Six Flags America   Washington  D.C.
Great Adventure Jackson New Jersey

error: class, interface, or enum expected line 94
error: class, interface, or enum expected line 99
```

I decided to change my code, because something didn't work out as expected, but now I am getting this. Can't get through the compilation. Any idea why it doesn't work? I am a complete noob about to abandon my java course.

Comment: Any chance you could indicate which lines are 94 and 99?

Answer (score 3):

Although indentation is confusing, the main method is outside of the class while it should be inside of it.

It also make the line `scan.close();` invalid, as `scan` is not defined there. remove the `}` before `scan.close();`.

Answer (score 2):

It's just because there's an extraneous closing brace in your first method here:

```
}
                  scan.close();
```

If you use an IDE such as eclipse or netbeans to edit your source files, it will help a lot with automatic brace matching and highlighting these kinds of errors.